# Перенос длинных строк кода с точкой, как правильно по pep8

Tags: python, code-style

Встал вопрос, как правильно и красиво сделать перенос длинной строки кода по PEP8 в месте точки:

```
result = list(
    MyModel.objects
        .filter(field1=100)
        .exclude(field2='a')
        .values_list(field3, flat=True))
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, вставив отступы в начале каждой строки перед точкой. Но autopep8 переформатирует:

```
result = list(
    MyModel.objects
    .filter(field1=100)
    .exclude(field2='a')
    .values_list(field3, flat=True))
```

Все бы ничего, но это код, над которым работает команда и она требует единой стилистики. Либо обосновать, почему надо ее изменить. Пытался искать и ничего не нашел. И да, первый вариант мне кажется более понятным и читаемым. Но если pep8 и в самом деле требует форматирования Вариант 2, то что ж, надо ему следовать. Да и просто при сохранении постоянное переформатирование происходит, а потом перед коммитом в репозиторий его убирать - лишние затраты.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768941/how-to-break-a-line-of-chained-methods-in-python

Comment: Да, именно второй вариант соответствует pep8.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, PEP8 рекомендует использовать скобки для разбиения длинных строк, но ничего не говорит об отступах внутри этих скобок. Я выравниваю вызовы методов по точкам и flake8 не видит в этом проблемы.

Comment: Вот явного требования в PEP8 я найти не могу. Есть для описания бинарных операций, но именно для точки даже похожего найти не могу. Но в целом мысль понятна, оставлю как автоформаттер. Посмотрим реакцию коллег на ревью

Answer (score 3):

Я в подобных случаях считаю самым удобочитаемым вариант при котором первый же кусочек с точкой идёт с новой строки:

```
result = list(
    MyModel
    .objects
    .filter(field1=100)
    .exclude(field2='a')
    .values_list(field3, flat=True)
    )
```

Никаких лишних отступов нет и автопроверка стиля не ругается.

Comment: В последней строке ')' лишний отступ.

Comment: Да, перенос по каждой точке и в самом деле был бы самый логичный. А вот скобку надо левее, отступ автоформаттер явно исправит.